# How should I modify logstash.conf to get the field I want?

Tags: nginx, logstash-configuration

I use the ELK + Filebeat , all version is 6.4.3 , the OS is windows 10

I add custom field in filebeat.yml , the key name is log_type , the value of log_type is nginx-access

The picture show part of filebeat.yml.

[image]

The content of logstash.conf is :

```
input {
    beats { 
       host => "0.0.0.0"
       port => "5544"
  } 
} 

filter {

mutate { 
  rename => { "[host][name]" => "host" } 
}   

if [fields][log_type] == "nginx-access" {
    grok {
                  match => { "message" => ["%{IPORHOST:[nginx][access][remote_ip]} - %{DATA:[nginx][access][user_name]} \[%{HTTPDATE:[nginx][access][time]}\] \"%{WORD:[nginx][access][method]} %{DATA:[nginx][access][url]} HTTP/%{NUMBER:[nginx][access][http_version]}\" %{NUMBER:[nginx][access][response_code]} %{NUMBER:[nginx][access][body_sent][bytes]} \"%{DATA:[nginx][access][referrer]}\" \"%{DATA:[nginx][access][agent]}\" \"%{DATA:[nginx][access][x_forwarded_for]}\" %{NUMBER:[nginx][access][request_time]}"] }
            }

mutate {
     copy => { "[nginx][access][request_time]" => "[nginx][access][requesttime]" }
  }

mutate {
      convert => {
      "[nginx][access][requesttime]" => "float"
    }
  }
}
}

output {
      stdout { 
       codec => rubydebug { metadata => true }
      }

      elasticsearch { 
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"] 
      } 
    }
```

When I use the command :

```
logstash.bat  -f  logstash.conf
```

The output is :

[image]

Question 1：

The field in the red box above is "requesttime" and "request_time" , what I want the field is nginx.access.requesttime and nginx.access.request_time，not requesttime and request_time 。 How should I modify logstash.conf to achieve my goal?

Question 2:

When I use the above logstash.conf , the field of the kibana management interface is only "request_time" field .

The picture show this :
[image]

If I want the "nginx.access.requesttime" field to also appear in the fields of the Kibana management interface, how should I modify the logstash.conf ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1:

I believe what you are looking for is

```
mutate {
   copy => { "[nginx][access][request_time]" => "nginx.access.requesttime" }
}
```

Question 2:

Whethere something is a keyword is determined by the template field mapping in Elasticsearch. Try the option above and see if the issue resolved.

[This issue in elastic forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/add-field-and-copy-data/109773) may help you.

Comment: Thanks very much.   
Which of the following two convert formats is correct?

mutate {
   convert => { "[nginx][access][requesttime]" => "float" }
}

mutate {
   convert => { "nginx.access.requesttime" => "float" }
}

Comment: Having that the convert is done after the copy you should use the "nginx.access.requesttime" since the event is already named like that. You can see in logstash source code [def copy(event)](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-mutate/blob/2df8f6d064f1304259a56136e09ed378abda93dd/lib/logstash/filters/mutate.rb#L531)

Comment: Thanks very much! @Gal S